# Qt tells me that my SLOT doesnt exist, but with a make clean, make it doesnt complain anymore

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

when i download a fresh copy from our SVN, make then run my program, Qt tells me that one of my SLOTS doesn't work but with a handy-dandy make clean then make, it seems to solve the problem. i continue to make changes in the code on my PC and that message never shows again.

C++
Qt 4.6
gcc

has anyone had this problem?
and ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt creates a whole bunch of metadata about your Q_OBJECT classes when you build. That metadata is stored in 'moc' files, one of which may have become inconsistent with your C++ code. It's usually a bad idea to store intermediate build stages in your version control system. I'd suggest running `make clean`, then looking at your VCS to find out what files got deleted, then commit the result.

In svn:

```
make clean
svn st     # you should see some files deleted
svn rm <all the deleted files that svn st showed>
svn ci -m "Cleaned out intermediate build stages"
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess? There's a file in your repository that's removed by `make clean` but not recreated by `make` (probably because it's no longer necessary), and it's something in this file that is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your .moc files in the repository (you shouldn't) then they could get out of sync with reality.  Does a `make includes` fix the problem too?

What all gets deleted when you do a `make clean`?  What all is there after you remake the project?  All files cleaned should be remade.  If they're not, like Anon. says, one of them could be doing strange things.